# Codeigniter inside codeigniter mod rewrite issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

so I have multiple codeigniter inside of codeigniter like this:

```
- application
    - controllers
    - models
    - views
- system
- index.php
- .htaccess
- foo
    - application
        - controllers
        - models
        - views
    - system
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
- bar
    - application
        - controllers
        - models
        - views
    - system
    - index.php
    - .htaccess
```

Everything has been running flawlessly. I can access all of the controllers and sub directories.

```
- www.myweb.com/controller_name/qwe
- www.myweb.com/foo/controller_name/qwerty
- www.myweb.com/bar/controller_name/qwer
```

And when I moved all of the codes into another server (new server with the same configurations & pointed it , I ran into problems.

```
- subdomain.myweb.com/controller_name/qwe  (working)
- subdomain.myweb.com/foo/controller_name/qwerty  (error not found)
- subdomain.myweb.com/foo/index.php/controller_name/qwerty   (working)
- subdomain.myweb.com/bar/controller_name/qwer  (working)
```

I suspect the problem lies within the .htaccess file. But I just don't understand which one is causing the problem.

```
.htaccess from the root:
====================================================
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Remove the index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>



.htaccess from subdir foo:
====================================================
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Remove the index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>



.htaccess from subdir bar:
====================================================
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bar/

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Remove the index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can somebody please tell me how can I fix this issue. so that I can access subdomain.myweb.com/foo/controller_name/qwerty correctly, without the need to use index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why are you using two codeingniter system folders? Do they have different versions?
You can have one codeigniter system to serve multiple applications, you just need to point it on your application folder...
Regarding your problem check your php configurations and logs, and see if there is any error...